# "Gedownloadet" oder "downgeloadet"?

Tags: verb, past-participle, anglicism

Windows gibt gerade Ersteres aus nach einem Update. Gibts hier eine grammatikalische Regel, die Windows kennt, aber ich nicht? Intuitiv habe ich bisher immer *downgeloadet* verwendet, wahrscheinlich wegen *heruntergeladen* …

Comment: Heruntergeladen. ***Punkt.***

Comment: Ich würde kopiere es dir auf die lokale Platte sagen. Herunterladen weckt zu leicht Assoziationen an herunterholen.

Comment: Tatsächlich verwenden wir scherzhaft die Formulierung "hol dir das mal eben runter [vom Server]" ;) Ich könnte sogar schwören, dass ich das mal in irgendeiner Software gesehen habe ("Update herunterholen...") - prinzpiell ja auch nicht verwerflich :)

Comment: @bernd_k Kannst du dir so einen Werbebanner vorstellen - "Jetzt kostenlos auf die lokale Platte kopieren!". Oder: hey, Peter, hab mir gestern ein nettes Video auf die lokale Platte kopiert. Echt hammer Vorschlag.

Comment: "downgeloadet" ist für mich grauenhafter Computerjargon.

Comment: Meine persönliche Meinung: Weder noch, klingt beides grauenhaft. Objektiv sind beide Varianten gleichermaßen richtig oder falsch.

Comment: Do not trust the Microsoft translations. Their quality went down significantly in the last few years.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Wie Bobby bereits in einem Kommentar erwähnt, ist natürlich "heruntergeladen" das bessere Wort.

"downgeloadet" ist zwar, wenn man schon vom Verb "downloaden" kommen möchte, die richtige Form, klingt aber trotzdem schräg. Häufig kann man auch alternative Formulierungen verwenden, z.B.:

> Der Download wurde erfolgreich abgeschlossen.

Der Nachteil beim Wort "herunterladen" ist, dass es keine direkte Relation zwischen dem Substantiv und dem Verb gibt. Download/downloaden vs. Download/herunterladen. Das spielt aber keine Rolle, wenn man sich vom Download verabschiedet und sich konkret auf das bezieht, was da heruntergeladen wurde, z.B. eine Datei oder ein Update:

> Die Datei wurde erfolgreich heruntergeladen.

Ups, kein englisches Wort mehr drin. Schwieriger wird's, wenn der Download nicht funktioniert. Die Formulierung

> Die Datei konnte nicht heruntergeladen werden.

klingt nämlich irgendwie nicht so genau wie

> Der Download ist fehlgeschlagen / wurde abgebrochen.

Aber das bekommt man auch hin mit entsprechenden Formulierungen.

Das erwähnte *Update* zeigt übrigens das gleiche Problem: Das Substantiv ist anerkannt, während sich eine Übersetzung (z.B. Aktualisierung) nicht richtig durchsetzt ("Patch" sagt man auch gerne, besonders bei Spielen). Beim Verb hingegen klingt "updaten" auch etwas komisch, weshalb hier im Text durchaus auf "aktualisieren" ausgewichen wird. Umgangssprachlich sagt man häufig trotzdem "updaten" ("hast du schon upgedatet?") und "patchen" (oder "Update/Patch installieren" - auch nicht viel besser).

Comment: `Download fehlgeschlagen` kann man mit `Herunterladen fehlgeschlagen` ersetzen. `Viele kostenlose Downloads` kann man mit `Viele Dateien / Filme / Was auch immer kostenlos herunterzuladen`. Das geht ja immer.

Comment: beim updaten hat man auch wieder dasgleiche Problem:  *upgedatet* oder *geupdatet* (Ich ziehe Letzteres vor). Gerade Windows hat einen seltsamen Geschmack bei diesen Begriffen -*der* statt *die Firewall* usw.

Comment: Das geht doch an der sprachlichen Realität vorbei. Die Wertung, "heruntergeladen" sei das "bessere Wort" (und das auch noch "natürlich") beruht auf persönlichem Geschmack; der sprachliche Alltag sieht anders aus. Die Antwort hier: http://www.grammatikfragen.de/showthread.php?58-quot-gedownloadet-quot-vs.-quot-downgeloaded-quot ist lesenswert

Comment: Wie entscheidest du bitte, was das "bessere" Wort ist? _Downgeloadet_ klingt für mich überhaupt nicht schräg, ich würde es in einem schriftsprachlichen Kontext halt nicht verwenden.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach: Die verlinkte Antwort geht aber überhaupt nicht darauf ein, ob man herunterladen oder downloaden verwenden sollte, sondern diskutiert nur, wie die Form *wahrscheinlich* gebildet werden muss (und besteht auch nur aus Vermutungen, die durch Google-Suchen "belegt" werden). Klar kann man englische Formulierungen verwenden, bei denen man nichtmal genau weiß, wie (siehe verlinkten Artikel), aber mein *persönlicher Geschmack* hält mich von sowas halt ab. Als "besser" bezeichne ich das Wort genau deshalb: Weil es a) deutsch ist und b) keine Zweifel über die Flexion gibt.

Comment: Ich denke halt, normative Antworten hier sollten nicht auf persönlichem Geschmack beruhen.

Answer (score 14):

Wie [0x6d64](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2358/gedownloadet-oder-downgeloadet/2359#2359) finde ich keine der beiden Varianten sprachlich gelungen. Inzwischen dürfte

> downgeloadet

als korrekt anerkannt sein:

- [Duden: downloaden (schwaches Verb)](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/downloaden)
- [canoo.net: Flexion von downloaden](http://canoonet.eu/services/Controller?dispatch=inflection&input=downloaden&features=(Cat%20V)(Aux%20haben)(Pref%20Detach)&country=D&lookup=caseInSensitive)

Die Tabelle bei canoo.net gibt alle Formen an, auch exotischere wie `du  downloadetest`. Sowas würde ich aber wahrscheinlich weder in Schrift noch Wort verwenden...

Comment: Ich mag "downgeloaded" auch lieber, weil ich in der übersetzten Form auch "heruntergeladen" sagen würde.

Comment: @Kage Dann würde ich "downgeloaden" vorziehen, und vielleicht wird sich später irgendwann "downgeladen" durchsetzen. Wer tut sich denn freiwillig "geloadet" an? Allerdings hätten wir dann Schwierigkeiten mit "upladen" :-)

Answer (score 6):

Mein Sprachgefühl stimmt dir zu, und zwar aus dem gleichen Grund. Wobei ich beide Formen bei allem Verständnis für das Verwenden von englischen Begriffen in der IT für ziemlich häßlich halte.

Comment: so auch der [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/downloaden)...