# Wie ist die richtige Schreibweise – "geliket"? "geliked"?

Tags: verb, spelling, past-participle, anglicism

Offen gestanden denke ich, dass es eher *geliket* sein müsste, da deutsche Partizipien gewöhnlich auf *t* enden, wie z. B. gemacht, getanzt, etc. Dagegen spricht meine Beobachtung, ich habe *geliket* fast noch nie gesehen, dementsprechend falsch sieht es für mich aus - selbst Google schlägt *geliked* vor, wenn man den Anfang tippt, außerdem hat *geliket* auch nur ein Fünftel der Treffer.

Irgendwelche Ideen?

Mir ist klar, dass sich das Wort in wahrscheinlich keinem Wörterbuch finden wird, es wird allerdings schon in der Umgangssprache verwendet.

Comment: http://hypermedia.ids-mannheim.de/call/public/fragen.ansicht?v_kat=19&v_id=140

Comment: related: ["Gedownloadet" oder "downgeloadet"?](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2358/gedownloadet-oder-downgeloadet)

Comment: Do people use gleich in German as we say in American Yiddish, "Gleichstu mein kleid?" (Do you like my dress?) I assume I'm understand the use of "geliked" correctly here...

Comment: @MartyGreen: The German verb ***gleichen*** and the English ***to like*** share etymologic roots with *got.* leikan, galeikan, *ahd.* lîchên, galîchên, *as.* lîkôn, *afries.* līkia, *ags.* lîcian, gelîcian, *anord.* lîka. Today the meaning is different however.

Comment: If we were consequent about assimilating English words into German, we would use "leiken" and "geleikt". As long as you use the English word I think you should use the English forms, too, that is "liked".

Comment: @Raphael That's not correct I think, there are many "eingedeutschte" words with English spelling and German pronounciation. Just look at 'designen' e.g. It works the other way around, too. They have 'to abseil' but most certainly do not say 'he abseilen', but rather 'he abseils'.

Comment: @heinrich5991 I don't think there is a "correct" here; I don't like any of these pseudo-eingedeutschte forms.

Comment: @Raphael But then again it's not about what you like but rather about what's common. And I guess even you *do* like some of these forms. Say, the plural of "Browser" in German is "Browser", not like in English "Browsers".

Comment: @heinrich5991 Well, as long as there are no "rules" I feel comfortable recommended using what I like, in the hope that these become more common. ;) Regarding your example with "Browser", you are right: I would use the "German" plural, but note the word is not mangled.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Das ist wieder richtig typisch. Natürlich ist es immer schöner, die deutsche Entsprechung zu benutzen, aber eben auch nur, wenn diese das Gleiche bedeutet. Das Verb *liken* bezieht sich lediglich auf das Drücken des Like-Buttons. Mag sein, dass das *mögen* voraussetzt, aber wenn man sich genau und unmissverständlich ausdrücken will, ist das Wort *liken* richtig. Wem das zu „cool“ und neumodisch erscheint, darf sich dann nicht wundern, wenn ihn keiner versteht. Das Wort wird übrigens sowohl im Netz als auch in der gesprochenen Sprache verwendet und das nicht nur bei Jugendlichen mit niedrigem Bildungsstand, nein auch bei älteren Menschen, die sich mit der Materie beschäftigen.

Und um auf die Frage zurückzukommen; *geliked* ist meines Erachtens geläufiger, aber ich versuche mich an die deutsche Konjugation zu halten und benutze *geliket.*

Comment: +1 für ein klares Statement. In der IT-Branche höre ich ständig "geliked" und jeder schreibt es anders. Ein "geliked" finde ich eher falsch, aber liest sich besser. Ich nutze auhch die Endung "ed".

Comment: Wäre die Antwort auch ohne den Rant möglich gewesen?

Comment: "Das ist wieder richtig typisch. Natürlich ist es (...)" - fehlt in der Frage irgendwas? Der Anfang klingt so, als würde er sich direkt auf eine Behauptung beziehen, dass hier ein Zusammenhang mit "mögen" bestehe; wo finde ich denn diesen Text?

Comment: Sorry, aber diese »Antwort« gibt keine klare Antwort auf die Frage, ob »geliked« oder »geliket« korrekt ist. Der erste Absatz beschäftigt sich mit Dingen, die gar nicht gefragt wurden, und der zweite Absatz gibt nur eine Beobachtung und eine persönliche Meinung wieder. Ich vermisse eine nachvollziehbare und klare Antwort auf die gestellte Frage.

Comment: ich bin mir ziemlich sicher dass es **geliked** heisst, da man anglizismen selten verändert. von der aussprache her kann man es ja dem deutsch anpassen und **"geleikt"** sagen.

Comment: @WayneEra „... da man anglizismen [sic.] selten verändert.“ Nach der Unlogik müsste es **liked** heißen, da das Anfügen der deutschen Vorsilbe **ge-** ja ebenfalls eine Veränderung ist.

Answer (score 17):

#### [Liken](http://szenesprachenwiki.de/definition/liken/)

Dies ist ein gutes Beispiel dafür, wie [kommerzialisierte](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/kommerzialisieren) (*sic*) Sprache (hier initiiert von Facebook) versucht, sich in der deutschen Umgangssprache einzunisten. Bislang existiert dieser [Neologismus](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neologismus) allerdings nur in der Szenesprache und dort hauptsächlich im [Netzjargon](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netzjargon). Deshalb ist es auch kaum verwunderlich, dass es keine grammatikalischen Regeln zur Verwendung dieses Anglizismus gibt. Im Netz herrscht schließlich eine gewisse grammatikalische Anarchie.

In einer ausführlichen Arbeit des [IDS Mannheim](http://hypermedia.ids-mannheim.de/call/public/fragen.ansicht?v_kat=19&v_id=140) wird versucht darzustellen, welche grammatikalische Formen ein solches Wort annehmen kann. Zu Verben, deren Stamm auf -t oder -d auslautet (dazu gehört auch *„liken“*), wird häufiger eine Endung *„-t“* gefunden als *„-ed“*, letztere wird als *„pseudoenglisch“* bezeichnet:

> Die skurrilen, pseudoenglischen Formen auf *-ed* sind im Internet seltener als die Formen auf *-et*, aber trotzdem sehr häufig. Sie sind sporadisch auch in den eher bildungssprachlich geprägten Textkorpora des IDS anzutreffen.

Welche der Endung sich bei *„liken“* durchsetzen wird, kann man heute noch nicht sicher abschätzen; nach der wesentlich häufigeren Verwendung von *„geliked“* gegenüber *„geliket“* könnte es durchaus die Endung *„-ed“* sein.

Beide Formen sind also „richtig“, wenn man so will.

---

#### Note in addition

Weitaus „richtiger“ im Sinn der deutschen Sprache wäre es allerdings, wenn man ein deutsches Wort fände. Man könnte z. B. das in der ursprünglichen Bedeutung identische deutsche Wort *„mögen“* nehmen. Dann hätte man auch keine Schwierigkeiten mit der Grammatik, sondern würde einfach sagen:

> „Ich habe Deinen Link von gestern *gemocht*.“

Das ist aber natürlich uncool, nicht im Sinne der Marketingstrategen, und es hat nicht die gleiche Bedeutung wie *„liken“*. Aber es entspricht der englischen Bedeutung von *„to like“*, die ja dort keinesfalls nur im Facebook-Kontext besteht.

Für die deutsche Lokalisierung sieht Facebook übrigens *„Gefällt mir“* vor:

[image]

Comment: Und eben da auf der deutschen Variante des Knopfes „Gefällt mir“ steht, würde „gemocht“ den Sinn verfehlen.

Comment: @Carsten Schultz: Ich gefälltmire den Beitrag. Ich habe den Beitrag gegefälltmirt.

Comment: Noch 2 Cents: bei 'liked' du mindestens weisst, dass es um ein Englisches Wort geht. 'Liken' ist in Gefahr, als 'licken' ausgesprochen werden.

Comment: @chirlu Das ist zwar lustig, aber sinnlos. Es heißt richtig: "Dein Beitrag gefällt mir. Dein Beitrag hat mir gefallen"

Comment: @Barth: Ich meine nicht alles zu 100% ernst. :) Aber „Dein Beitrag hat mir gefallen“ bedeutet nicht das Gleiche wie „Ich habe den Gefällt-mir-Knopf unter deinem Beitrag gedrückt“. Das kann jemand tun, ohne daß ihm der Beitrag tatsächlich gefallen hat, oder auch nicht tun, obwohl er ihm gefallen hat.

Comment: Der Punkt vom @CarstenS ist aber dass Fejsbukk AG auf diese Neologismen gar nicht besteht, ganz egal in welchem Zusammenhang und in welcher nicht englischer Sprache.  Ich lajke das ganze nicht so sehr aber man muss objektiv bleiben.

Comment: @AdamM.B.: das liegt aber vielleicht auch daran, dass bislang alle Versuche von Facebook "LIKE" patentieren zu lassen gescheitert sind ([Beispiel](http://tsdr.uspto.gov/documentviewer?caseId=sn85020084&docId=APP20100424081940#docIndex=21&page=1)) und sie deshalb auch gar nicht darauf bestehen können.

Comment: @Takkat Das ist, denke ich, irrelevant.  Sie *dürften* es schon machen.  Außerdem wurde FB von Freiwilligen übersetzt.  Ich kann Dir gut sagen dass internationale Sprachpolitik nicht zu den Prioritäten der Firma gehört.  Lokalisierungsfragen werden nur in der relevanten Abteilung diskutiert, und darum geht es um *anpassen* womöglich, Firmen wollen so lokal und einheimisch wirken wie möglich.  Diese Feinheiten des Deutschen interessieren halt dort in der Bay Area kaum ein Schwein.

Answer (score 9):

Es gibt überhaupt keinen Grund, die Schreibweise der Vergangenheitsform aus dem Englischen zu übernehmen. Man nimmt die Grundform und passt sie den grammatischen Begebenheiten des Deutschen an. "Gelikt" ist die einzig richtige Form:

- holen - geholt
- machen - gemacht
- streamen - gestreamt
- twittern - getwittert
- liken - gelikt

Comment: Ohne das _e_ ist das Wort aber vollkommen undurchsichtig.

Comment: Es geht ja nicht darum, was verständlich ist, sondern was korrekt ist

Comment: Es scheint Konsens zu sein, dass "gelik(e)t" die richtige Form ist - ob nun mit oder ohne e. Ich denke, dass es sinnvoller wäre, "like" als Stamm anzusehen und daher als Partizip "geliket" zu haben.

Comment: @MartinHansen Korrekter wäre aber keine dieser Formen zu akzeptieren und stattdessen die deutsche Wörter zu nutzen.

Comment: @Martin Hansen: Problem mit *gelikt* ist nicht nur, dass es das englische Wort *like* in der Mitte durchtrennt, sondern auch dass das e für die Aussprache relevant ist (vgl. *strip/stripe*, *sit/site*). Das eingedeutschte Verb hat damit eigentlich den Stamm *like* (und nicht *lik)* und Fälle wie *like-en* werden zu zu *liken* verkürzt. Ähnliches passiert übrigens auch mit »normalen« Verben: *öffnen – geöffnet* (und nicht *geöffnt); atmen – geatmet.*

Comment: @c.p.: Ein Wort kann stilistisch noch so grauenvoll sein: Eine gute Ortografie muss dennoch eine Antwort auf die Frage haben, wie es zu schreiben ist – und sei es auch nur zur Wiedergabe der Sprache von Banausen.

Comment: _nicht darum, was verständlich ist, sondern was korrekt ist_: Die Rechtschreibung ist ja kein Naturgesetz, sondern Konvention; und da sollte man schon auch die Verständlichkeit im Blick haben (neben anderen Kriterien wie Konsistenz). Ich stimme hier @Wrzlprmft zu, man muß sich allerdings auch bewußt sein, daß Duden und Wahrig diesen Fall anders sehen ([timen, getimt](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/timen)). – Andere Sprachen passen Fremdwörter stärker an und schreiben das Äquivalent zu _teimen, geteimt_ bzw. _leiken, geleikt_.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Das eingedeutschte Wort hat den Stamm "liken" und nicht "like". Der Wortstamm wird mit eingedeutscht. Daher behandelt man "liken/gelikt" analog wie "machen/gemacht". Vgl. auch andere, mittlerweile akzeptierte Eindeutschungen wie "tunen/getunt". Die Rechtschreibung in Bezug auf die Aussprache ist irrelevant, da es sich um ein Fremdwort handelt. Wenn man diesen Faktor mit einbeziehen will, müsste man den Wortstamm schon im Vorfeld ändern und der deutschen Aussprache anpassen ("leiken").

Comment: @chirlu: Die Verständlichkeit ist eben ein sehr schwammiger Begriff. Für mich sind Wörter wie "gelikt", "getimt" und "getunt" ausreichend verständlich, allein deshalb schon, weil ihre Bedeutung meist aus dem Kontext erkennbar ist. "Gelikt" wird höchstens als ungewohnt empfunden, weil es sich eben falsch als "geliked" eingebürgert hat. Das kann aber kein Kriterium für die richtige Rechtschreibung sein.

Comment: 1) Mit Stamm habe ich hier nicht den Infinitiv, sondern den Inflektiv gemeint. Der analoge Stamm von *machen* wäre *mach.* 2) Wieso muss *liken* analog zu *machen* sein und nicht z. B. zu *öffnen?* 3) Der Ausspracheaspekt verdeutlicht vor allem, dass im Englischen das e genauso zur *lik(e)*-Silbe gehört wie das a zur *stream*-Silbe (auch wenn es ungewohnt sein mag, dass ein stummer Vokal hinter dem auslautenden Konsonanten einer Silbe deren Vokal beeinflusst) und deswegen nicht von dieser getrennt werden sollte (wenn man für diese Silbe bei der englischen Rechtschreibung bleiben möchte).

Comment: Bei twittern gibt's keine grosse Gefahr, aber wenn man eine Form wie 'gelikt' sieht, wird man das nicht als 'gelickt' lesen wollen?

Comment: _Liken_ wird nicht analog zu _öffnen_ / _geöffnet_ behandelt, weil der Schlussteil bei 'geöffnet' am Ende aus zwei Silben bestehen muss, da das 'öffnt ' in 'geöffnt' keine geläufige Schlusssilbe im Deutschen darstellen würde. Bei _gelikt_ besteht der Endteil analog zu Wörtern wie _gesagt_ oder _geparkt_ aus einer Schlussilbe und kommt daher ohne zusätzliches e aus.

Answer (score 7):

Wenn jemand *liket* o. Ä. sagt, wird er mit ziemlicher Sicherheit die deutsche Konjugation im Kopf haben und nicht die aussprachegleiche englische. Deswegen ist es eigentlich ziemlich absurd, hier die Orthografie englischer Konjugationsformen (also z. B. *liked)* zu verwenden. Drei Beispiele, die dies verdeutlichen:

> *Er liked den Link. (Er mag den Link.)

Der Sprecher möchte hiermit über die Gegenwart reden, *liked* ist aber eine Vergangenheitsform und wäre deswegen selbst im Englischen falsch.

> *Wir haben abgelosed. (Wir haben verloren.)

Hier wird zwar über die Vergangenheit geredet, aber die vermeintliche Vergangenheitsform *losed* existiert im Englischen schlichtweg nicht. Beide Vergangenheitsformen von *to lose* sind *lost. (abgelost* ist zwar als deutsche Konjugation denkbar, wird dann aber nicht so ausgesprochen wie die englische Vergangenheitsform.)

> *Er hat die upgeloadete Datei downgeloaded. (Er hat die hochgeladene Datei heruntergeladen.)

Im Deutschen sind *d* und *t* im Auslaut zwar in der Aussprache nicht unterscheidbar (wegen der Auslautverhärtung), werden in der Rechtschreibung aus gutem Grund unterschieden, nämlich um die Rechtschreibung konsistent zu gebeugten Varianten des Worts zu halten, in denen der Unterschied eine Rolle spielen kann: Beispielsweise werden *Rat* und *Rad* gleich ausgesprochen, die Genitive *Rates* und *Rades* aber eben nicht.

Da niemand (außerhalb gewisser Dialekte) *upgeloadede* sagt, muss *upgeloadet* konsequenterweise eben so geschrieben werden (und *downgeloadet* analog).

Kurzum: Auf Basis der Schreibweise *geliked* lässt sich keine konsistente Orthografie errichten.

---

Die offiziellen Rechtschreibregeln decken diesen Fall leider nicht ganz klar ab. Die relevanten Regeln sind:

> **§ 22** Als grundlegend im Sinne dieser orthografischen Regelung gelten die
>   folgenden Laut-Buchstaben-Zuordnungen.
>
> […]
>
> Laute – Buchstaben – Beispiele
>   […]
>   [t] – *t – tragen, Tür, fort, Optimum*

> **§ 23** Die in großen Teilen des deutschen Sprachgebiets auftretende Verhärtung der Konsonanten [b], [d], [ց], [v] und [z] am Silbenende sowie vor anderen Konsonanten innerhalb der Silbe wird in der Schreibung nicht berücksichtigt.
>
> E1: Bei vielen Wörtern kann die Schreibung aus der Aussprache erweiterter
>   Formen oder verwandter Wörter abgeleitet werden, in denen der betreffende
>   Konsonant am Silbenanfang steht, zum Beispiel:
>
> Konsonant am Silbenende usw. – Konsonant am Silbenanfang
>   […]
>   *Rad, Radumfang – Rades, rädern* (aber *Rat – Rates)*

> **§ 32** Über die bisher dargestellten Laut-Buchstaben-Zuordnungen hinaus
>   treten in Fremdwörtern auch fremdsprachige Zuordnungen auf.

Regel 22 erfordert hier ein *t* am Wortende *(geliket* oder *gelikt).* Regel 23 rüttelt daran aus den oben angegebenen Gründen nicht: *Gelikete* wird mit [t] ausgesprochen.

Regel 32 könnte daran rütteln, da *geliket* klar ein Fremdwort ist. Andererseits entstammt das gesprochene [t] am Ende eben nicht dem Englischen, sondern dem Deutschen. Deshalb sehe ich keinen Grund, es als “fremdsprachige Zuordnung” zu behandeln und *geliked* als gültig anzusehen.

---

Offen ist hingegen meines Erachtens die Frage, ob *geliket* oder *gelikt* richtig ist. Man kann dem *e* in *to like* eine aussprachliche Relevanz zuweisen und den Standpunkt vertreten, dass es anzeigt, dass das Wort [laɪk] (leik) und nicht [lɪk] (lick) auszusprechen ist (vgl. *strip/stripe, sit/site).* Demnach wäre *gelikt* entstellend und man könnte das Wort genausogut komplett deutsch schreiben, also *geleikt.*

Andererseits ist die englische Rechtschreibung eh weit von Phonetizität entfernt und ein »stiller« Vokal an dieser Stelle ist im Deutschen äußerst ungewöhnlich.

Mir ist keine offizielle Regelung bekannt, die hier anwendbar wäre. Ich würde deshalb sowohl *geliket* als auch *gelikt* als zulässig einstufen (aber persönlich *geliket* bevorzugen).

Answer (score 4):

Die korrekte Konjugation ist...

> **gelikt**

Dies wurde bereits [in einer anderen Antwort gesagt](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/4435/wie-ist-die-richtige-schreibweise-geliket-geliked/8477#8477), ich möchte dies hier aber nochmals mit ein paar Links bekräftigen.

So heißt es zum Beispiel auf [Canoonet's blog](https://blog.canoonet.eu/2015/10/09/liken-likte-gelikt/):

> Man nimmt die Grundform liken, schneidet die Endung en ab und hängt die regelmäßigen Verbendungen an:
>
> liken
> ich like, du likst, er likt
> ich likte, du liktest, er likte
> ich habe gelikt

Der Duden hat das Verb [liken](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/liken) übrigens bereits aufgenommen, Hinweise auf die korrekte Konjugation finden sich dort aber bisher leider nicht.
Hier kann man aber zum Vergleich das ähnliche Verb *[faken](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/faken)* zur Hilfe nehmen. Das Partizip, laut Duden, ist *gefakt*.

Überhaupt so ziemlich jede Quelle im Internet unterstützt die Schreibweise ohne *E*. Hier eine kleine Auswahl:

- [deutschegrammatik20.de](https://deutschegrammatik20.de/verbformen/die-konjugation-praesens/die-konjugation-von-anglizismen-im-prasens/)
- [welt.de](https://www.welt.de/debatte/kolumnen/der-onliner/article117825999/Heisst-es-geliket-oder-geliked-oder-gelikt.html)
- [annika-lamer.de](https://www.annika-lamer.de/so-konjugieren-sie-englische-verben-im-deutschen/)
- [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/liken)

---

Abschließend muss natürlich erwähnt sein, dass die meistgewählte Form *geliked* ist und Google bei einer Suche nach *gelikt* sogar die falsche Schreibweise vorschlägt. Den Regeln entspricht dies aber nicht.

Comment: To be fair, I wouldn't be able to pronounce likt or fakt if I read it. I can't take the Duden seriously on that one, sorry.

Answer (score -1):

Auf [www.googlefight.com](http://www.googlefight.com) ist die Antwort klar: 30'200 zu 4950 für "geliked"

Comment: Das beantwortet was häufiger verwendet wird, nicht was richtig ist.

Comment: Provided Google counts are accurate, which they aren't...