# Gibt es ein Verb für "Ein Zeichen wird durch seine Escape-Sequenz ersetzt"?

Tags: spelling, technical-terminology, anglicism

Beim Programmieren (oder LaTeX-Schreiben) müssen manche Zeichen durch [Escape-Sequenzen](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape-Sequenz) ersetzt werden.

Beispiel (in LaTeX):

```
Ich habe 10$.
```

Wird zu

```
Ich habe 10\$.
```

da `$` ein für den mathmode reserviert wird.

Was sagt man dazu? Sagt man "Dollar wird escaped"? Schreibt man escaped oder escapet oder escapt?

Comment: Zur Rechtschreibung siehe [diese Frage](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/4435/wie-ist-die-richtige-schreibweise-geliket-geliked).

Comment: Jap. *Escapen* ist das Verb.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### maskieren

Ein vielleicht mittlerweile weniger gebräuchlicheres Verb für *"to escape"* in der EDV-Fachsprache ist *"maskieren"*. Man könnte also wie folgt sagen:

> In LaTeX wird ein Dollarzeichen mit einem Gegenschrägstrich maskiert.

Vermutlich wird aber hier ein Anglizismus besser verstanden, als eine deutsche Übersetzung:

> In LaTeX wird ein Dollarzeichen mit einem Backslash escapet *(bzw. escaped)*.

Comment: Ich würde auch maskieren verwenden und finde es daher auch durchaus verständlich.

Comment: Meine Zustimmung für das maskieren, keine für `besser: escaped` (geflüchtet?).

Comment: @userunknown Für Fachleute ist letzteres vermutlich in der Tat verständlicher. Im Allgemeingebrauch eher ersteres.

Answer (score 1):

Als Verb wird allgemein *escapen* verwendet. Ob man nun escaped oder escapet sagt, wird - wie bereits in den Kommentaren verlinkt - auch recht gut in dieser Frage eingegangen: [Wie ist die richtige Schreibweise – "geliket"? "geliked"?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/4435/wie-ist-die-richtige-schreibweise-geliket-geliked)

Comment: Ich persönlich ziehe ja `escaped` vor ...