# Gute Übersetzung für "liken"

Tags: single-word-request

Ich habe immer wieder das Problem, dass es keine gute Übersetzung für das englische Verb "like" gibt, die im Zusammenhang Social Media verwendet werden kann. Auf Englisch kann man einen Inhalt, Post "liken" (übler Anglizismus), aber auf Deutsch kann man ihn …? Das Beste, was mir bisher eingefallen ist, ist "… mit 'Gefällt mir' markieren", aber das ist unhandlich und liest sich nicht sonderlich schön.

Gibt es eine gute Vokabel für das englische "like", die ich (in einem wissenschaftlichen Text, nicht umgangssprachlich!) im Kontext soziales Netzwerk für ebendieses "gefällt mir" verwenden könnte und die auch genau so verstanden wird?

Comment: Mein Eindruck ist, daß sich "liken" allmählich als feststehender Ausdruck für die Tätigkeit des "gefällt mir" - klickens in sozialen Netzwerken etabliert. Eine Antwort habe ich selbst nicht, bin aber sehr gespannt, was hierbei heraus kommt.

Comment: Ich auch ^^. Ja, das liken macht sich breit ... aber das ist so unschön, solche Anglizismen sind doch eine Seuche ... und meinem Prof kann ich keine Hausarbeit abgeben, in der ich schreibe, wie viel in sozialen Netzwerken doch geliked wird ^^'

Comment: Eventuell kannst Du, indem Du zunächst den Vorgang beschreibst, dann erwähnst, daß sich hier der Begriff durchzusetzen scheint, und Du ihn daher in der Folge verwendest?

Comment: Ja das wird wohl die Notfall-Lösung, falls hier kein guter Vorschlag kommt ... will ich aber nach Möglichkeit vermeiden, das sieht so hässlich aus in meinem Text >.>

Comment: related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/4435/wie-ist-die-richtige-schreibweise-geliket-geliked

Comment: Ich halte es ebenfalls für vertretbar, "liken" (in Anführungszeichen) zu schreiben. Im hochprofessionellen Kontext würde ich "favorisieren" oder "mit einem 'Gefällt mir' markieren" benutzen.

Comment: "Favorisieren" klingt nicht schlecht, werde ich in Erwägung ziehen!

Comment: @Œlrim: "favorisieren" imploziert für mich, dass es auch etwas gibt, dem gegenüber ich etwas favorisiere. Wenn mir alles gefällt, würde ich ggf. alles liken, aber alles zu favorisieren klingt irgendwie merkwürdig.

Comment: Was ist unhandlich und unschön an Gefällt mir?  Liken ist nur Internet Jargon, als Deutsch würde ich das nicht ansehen.

Comment: Naja, an sich nichts, problematisch wird es, wenn ich davon schreibe, dass Leute einen bestimmten Inhalt ... liken. Dann wird daraus direkt ein ganzer Nebensatz, so "... wird von denjenigen mit "Gefällt mir" markiert", klingt nicht gut und bläht den Text auf. Gerade wenn man die Formulierung mehrmals verwendet (in Ermangelung von Synonymen) liest sich das nicht flüssig ...

Comment: mögen bzw. mag ich

Comment: @Andie2302: Das ist ja was ganz anderes. Man kann schließlich auch etwas liken, ohne es zu mögen, oder etwas mögen, ohne es zu liken.

Comment: _Gefällt mir_ ist gar nicht schlecht. Wenn es kürzer sein soll, kann man eventuell _mir_ weglassen.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sprache lebt. Konservative Menschen wehren sich zwar gewohnheitsmäßig gegen jede Veränderung, das wird die Veränderungen aber nicht aufhalten. Tatsache ist, dass es im deutschen Sprachraum längst ein etabliertes Verb für das englische »liken« gibt. Es lautet:

> liken

Das Wort ist unter den Benutzern sozialer Netzwerke weit verbreitet, und es wird von dieser Personengruppe auch gut verstanden.

Comment: Das "von dieser Personengruppe" ist halt ein Problem, wenn den Text auch von Leuten außerhalb dieser Gruppe gelesen werden soll ... Und gerade in einem seriösen Text klingt es einfach hässlich ... Aber Du hast wohl recht, ein wirklich gutes Wort, das die Bedeutung auch trifft, gibt es nicht ...

Comment: Ein Kompromiss bestünde vielleicht darin, am Anfang der Arbeit einmalig den Ausdruck "mit 'Gefällt mir' markieren" als umgangssprachlichen Netzjargon für "liken" vorzustellen und im Folgenden immer (oder so oft wie stilistisch nötig) "liken" in Anführungszeichen zu benutzen. Eine Nennung im Glossar o.ä. wäre vielleicht auch möglich.

Comment: @Gin-San: Wenn sich ein Fachterminus innerhalb einer bestimmten Personengruppe etabliert hat, der außerhalb dieser Gruppe ungebräuchlich ist, dann hat man immer das Problem, diesen Begriff erst bekannt zu machen wenn man ihn außerhalb dieser Gruppe verwenden will. Beispiel: Jeder Chemiker wird wissen, was »titrieren« ist. Das ist unter Chemikern ein weit verbreiteter und gängiger Begriff. Aber wenn du für Nicht-Chemiker einen Text schreibst, in dem diese Tätigkeit erwähnt wird, wirst du diesen Begriff erst erklären müssen. Selbst dann wenn du ihn hässlich finden solltest.

Comment: @Gin-San: Ich finde es zwar prinzipiell nett, wenn man mir recht gibt, aber du gibst mir in einer Sache recht, die ich gar nicht gesagt (und auch nicht gemeint) habe. Ich habe NICHT gesagt, es gäbe kein wirklich gutes Wort, das die Bedeutung trifft. Ich habe das genaue Gegenteil geschrieben. Ich habe geschrieben, dass es sehr wohl ein wirklich gutes Wort gibt, das die Bedeutung ganz exakt trifft. Dieses Wort ist: »liken«.

Comment: Muss ich direkt mal **liken** mit einer positiven Bewertung :D

Answer (score 3):

Aus dem Stand fallen mir: *gut finden*, *mögen*, *plussen*, *applaudieren* und *empfehlen* ein.
Ich kann nicht feststellen, dass der Begriff sich außerhalb eines einzigen Netzwerks etabliert, es sieht mir mehr so aus, als wären andere Netze bemüht, genau diesen Begriff zu vermeiden: Z. B. *retweeten*, *teilen*.
Mir ist auch nicht genau klar, warum wir im Deutschen einen "Fachbegriff" benötigen für "auf die Grafik mit dem Daumen-Hoch-Symbol klicken", während für die englischsprachige Bevölkerung ein normales Verb ausreicht – für komplexere Sätze als "Liken Sie uns" ein deutlicher Vorteil.

Natürlich haben Em1 und Hubert Schölnast recht, wenn sie ausführen, dass technisch retweet etwas anderes bedeutet; ich bin aber nicht davon überzeugt, dass der Unterschied in der ursprünglichen Frage relevant ist. Ich verstehe das Szenario so, dass man über einen Artikel/Bild/Posting/Tweet stolpert und ihn mit den Mitteln des jeweiligen Mediums unterstützen möchte. Ob das nun nur auf eine Statistik wirkt oder für wen auch immer namentlich erkennbar ist und welche technische Umsetzung vorliegt, halte ich für nebensächlich.

Comment: "normales Verb" - na ja. Ohne den Facebook-Kontext würden englische Sätze wie "Like us!" (genau so, im Imperativ!) oder "Have you already liked us?" auch nur sehr begrenzt einen Sinn ergeben (und eigentlich auch nicht den, den die Sätze ohne diesen Facebook-Kontext hätten). Auch im Englischen wurde also ein "Fachbegriff" geschaffen, der eben nur weniger weit entfernt ist von einem existierenden Wort derselben Sprache.

Comment: "retweeten" und "teilen" sind auch ganz andere Dinge als "liken" und bei FB kann man auch "teilen". – In der Umgangssprache wird schlicht von "auf Gefällt-mir klicken" gesprochen, wenn "liken" vermieden werden soll.

Comment: Em1 hat vollkommen recht: liken, retweeten und teilen sind drei verschiedene Aktivitäten: Liken: Durch Anklicken des entsprechenden Buttons zu erkennen geben, dass einem der Artikel/Kommentar gefällt. Retweeten: Einen Tweet (Twitter-Beitrag) eines anderen Autors an die eigenen Follower weiterleiten. Teilen (übrigens ein deutsches Wort!): Einen Beitrag eines anderen Autors in der eigenen Timeline posten. Retweeten und Teilen sind einander also sehr ähnlich, aber liken ist etwas ganz anderes. Durch das Liken eines Beitrags wird dieser Beitrag nicht ein weiteres Mal veröffentlicht.

Answer (score 3):

```
Hochwerten
```

wäre ein Begriff, der wohl von jedem verstanden wird, aber weil er nicht benutzt wird, löst er bestimmt überall leichtes Befremden aus. Daher würde ich in den meisten Fällen wohl eher zum *Liken* greifen.
*Aufwerten* könnte man auch geneigt sein zu etablieren, aber das könnte manchmal zu Doppeldeutigkeiten führen – wenn jemand meinen Beitrag aufwertet, dann würde ich vermuten, es war Loong, der die Zeichensetzung korrigiert hat. :)

Comment: Genau, "aufwerten" beinhaltet für mich unzweifelhaft eine aktive Änderung, nicht nur eine passive Bewertung.

Answer (score 3):

Das Grundproblem ist, dass sich auch schon in der englischen Sprache das Verb *to like* in der Bedeutung »in einem blauen sozialen Netzwerk das Feld mit dem nach oben gereckten Daumen anklicken« von dem Verb *to like* in der Bedeutung »etwas mögen« auseinanderentwickelt. Persönlich bin ich zwar nicht auf dem entsprechenden Netzwerk unterwegs, aber mein Eindruck ist, dass es nur eine Bewertungsmöglichkeit – eben *I like this* – gibt. Diese wird dann für alle Beiträge, die man für ausreichend interessant hält, verwendet. Wenn nun eine Nachricht auftaucht wie »David Bowie ist heute gestorben!« wird ohne mit der Wimper zu zucken der entsprechende Knopf gedrückt – und zwar gerade auch von denjenigen, die im wahren Leben niemals sagen würden »I like the fact that he’s dead« – »mir gefällt, dass er tot ist« –, gerade von seinen Fans.

An diesem Unterschied leiden bisher alle Versuche, ein Nichtfremdwort für das markieren eines solchen Beitrags zu etablieren. Es müsste ja schließlich ein Wort sein, dass

1. schnell und einfach, ohne viele Vorkenntnisse verstanden wird
2. das Prinzip adäquat beschreibt
3. nicht sofort unterstellt, dass man Gefallen am markierten findet
4. aber auch klarmachen können, dass *to like* und *to like* manchmal eben doch beide zugleich gemeint sind.

Ein solches Verb neu zu erfinden ist schwer, zumal viele Deutsche auch Englisch können und sich auf Englisch *to like* durch die schiere Allgegenwärtigkeit auf eben jenem Medium durchgesetzt hat. Es ist einfach am nächsten gelegen, dieses Wort so direkt zu übertragen, sodass auf Deutsch die erste oben angedeutete Bedeutung von *to like* eben mit *liken* übersetzt wird, während für die zweite weiterhin *mögen* verwendet wird.