# Ein kürzeres Wort für programmieren

Tags: english-to-german, single-word-request, synonym

Ich such nach einem kürzeren Wort für "programmieren" oder ein eingedeutschtes Wort für "Coden".
Ich möchte nämlich eine Internetpräsenz haben, in der ich kurz und knapp meinen Vornamen plus das was ich mache (programmieren).
Damit diese Wortkombination nicht allzu lang ist, will ich das oben genannte Wort finden.
Ich habe an folgendes gedacht " Coded". Oder wäre es dann " Codet" irgendwie klingt das beides falsch, wäre aber perfekt weil es kurz und knackig ist.
" programmiert" wäre mir schon ein wenig zu lang.

Comment: Zu *codet* vs. *coded* siehe [diese Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/4435/2594).

Comment: *Hackt.* – *Coden* einzudeutschen ist keine so gute Idee.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft ah danke, also tendiert man dann in diesem Fall eher zu Codet oder?

Comment: @Janka heeey, *hackt* ist auch eine sehr coole Idee, danke!

Comment: @Janka: Das sollte eine Antwort sein.

Comment: Es wäre hilfreich, um gute Alternativen zu sehen, wenn du einmal den gesamten Text (oder einen Screenshot) dieser Stelle auf deiner Website zeigtest. Bestimmte Alternativen drängen sich vielleicht erst durch den konkreten Kontext auf.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann es geht darum eine Internetpräsenz aufzubauen. Mein Ziel dabei ist es einen YouTube Channel mit Tutorials zu öffnen und auch Social Media wie Instagram oder Twitter zu benutzen und eine Internet-Domain zu haben. Damit die Leute auch meine Webseite einfach eingeben und meine Social Media Accounts einfach finden können, wäre es super wenn der @ oder die Domain relativ kurz gehalten ist. Das ist der Grund warum ich programmiert nicht so gut finde. Außerdem sollte es kurz, prägnant und einprägsam sein :)

Comment: Codieren und Programmieren sind nicht dasselbe! Der Programmierer muss sich meist einen Algorithmus überlegen, um eine vorgegebene Aufgabe lösen zu können. Der Codierer bekommt hingegen den fertigen Algorithmus und muss nur mehr den Code schreiben.

Comment: Eine Sprache ist kein stetiges Konstrukt sondern entwickelt sich ständig weiter. Von Verschandelung zu sprechen finde ich da unpassend konservativ.

Comment: Warum soll "programmieren" zu lang sein? Das ist Blödsinn. "Hacken" ist falsch, da es negativ behaftet ist (Angriff auf ein Software-System). Hacken ist nicht programmieren, wenn es im Jargon auch als lustig gemeint teilweise so verwendet wird. Prüfe, was die Zielgruppe deiner Homepage ist. Ansonsten wirst du schnell als nichtprofessionell enttarnt werden.

Comment: Die einzige halbwegs allgemeinverständliche Alternative im Deutschen ist *entwickeln*, was aber nur eine Silbe kürzer ist.

Comment: @ Janka: "Coden einzudeutschen ist keine so gute Idee." - Das Verb *coden* steht bereits in deutschen Wörterbüchern. :-) Ob's auch im Ö-Wb steht, weiß ich nicht.

Comment: @äüö: '"Hacken" ist falsch, da es negativ behaftet ist (Angriff auf ein Software-System).' - schlimmer als das. Im Programmierkontext habe ich bei "hacken" eigentlich keine Assoziation mit einem Angriff auf ein Software-System (der Netzwerk-bezogenen Bedeutung von "hacken"). Vielmehr wird "hacken" bzw. insbesondere "der Hack" als das Programmieren einer gerade so funktionierenden Notlösung, die jedoch gegen alle bewährten Standards verstößt und eventuell sogar selber schwerwiegende Probleme hervorrufen kann, verstanden.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Coden könnte bereits als ausreichend eingedeutscht betrachtet werden.

Es gibt darüber hinaus wenige Möglichkeiten:

- ***hackt*** – die geeky Variante ist abgeleitet von [Hacker](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hacker), hacken und ist bei Programmierern eine Anspielung auf das Rumhacken auf der Tastatur. Es ist allerdings etwas zu untergrundig, weil es eben bei Otto Normalspiesser den Hauch des Illegalen verbreitet. Wenn das gewünscht wird…
- ***codet*** – sollte nicht nur im sächsischen Sprachraum mit Sorgfalt ausgesprochen werdem, weil dieser Anglizismus einfach Scheiße klingt.
- ***kodiert*** – is leicht daneben. Klingt entweder versnobt oder schlicht falsch, da das eher auf Verschlüsselung anzuwenden verstanden wird.
- ***proggt*** – scheint wieder etwas aus der Mode zu sein, war aber szenetypisch im deutschen Sprachraum. Etwas -tümelnd, aber der Gleichklang zu 'rockt' macht für einige einiges wett.

Im direkten Vergleich zu

```
programmiert
```

böte sich vielleicht noch der kleine Vorteil bei

```
entwickelt
```

an. Das ist zwar zutreffend, aber zugleich unpräzise. Ohne Kontext denken da viele wohl an einen stolzen Maulbeerseidenspinnerfacharbeiter?

Deutsch ist das Königreich des Nominalstils, daher

- ***Coder*** – immer noch ein Anglizismus, aber kurz und passend anzuwenden.
- ***[Dev](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Dev)*** – wiederum identischer Einwand, aber kürzer geht's wohl nimmer, und das Ursprungswort *[Developer](https://de.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Developer)* dürfte inzwischen auch im deutschen Sprachraum bekannt sein. Wenn nicht, [Wiederholungen schleifen's ein.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vhh_GeBPOhs)

---

Generelle Einwendungen gegen diese Beispiele und Vorschläge, die es zu berücksichtigen gilt:

> @user_unknown: An proggt stört mich das kurze o, das in programmiert nicht heimisch ist. "Hackt" sehe ich genauso - kommt drauf an, ob man sich an Insider richtet, sonst klingt es vielen wie "crackt". Wenn "programmiert" zu groß ist, würde ich eine kleinere Schrift wählen.
>
> @Björn_Friedrich: Ich kann mir den Kommentar einfach nicht verkneifen: Für mich ist das eine Verschandelung der Sprache. Statt gecodet wird allenfalls kodiert; und wenn jemand sagt, er hacke, dann steht er vor meinem geistigen Auge mit Beil bewaffnet vor einem Holzstumpf. Allerdings komme ich schon bei der Aussage, das Wort programmieren sei zu lang, nicht mit. Aber vielleicht bin ich mit Mitte dreißig doch schon zu alt für diesen neumodischen Sprachquatsch
>
> @Janka: Hackt. – Coden einzudeutschen ist keine so gute Idee.

Comment: ***Kodieren*** ist der Vorgang einen Algorithmus mit Hilfe einer Programmiersprache umzusetzen. Somit hat das nur soweit etwas mit verschlüsseln zu tun als dass das Ergebnis nicht einfach lesbar ist. Ein kryptographischer Vorgang ist das aber nicht. Auch der Morsecode ist ein Alphabeth wie auch der ASCII Code. Daher kann ich der Aussage, "kodiert sei schlicht falsch" nicht folgen. Siehe auch: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code

Comment: @harper Den Ausführungen zu "kodieren" selbst stimme ich völlig zu, nur schreibe ich nicht "sei falsch", sondern gerade nur "klingt falsch" und "wird so verstanden". Wenn ich mich da irre, seufze ich von nun an über über meine Dummheit anstatt die der Allgemeinheit ;)

Comment: "*Klingt ... schlicht falsch, da das eher auf Verschlüsselung anzuwenden verstanden wird.*" wurde nicht von der Allgemeinheit geschrieben.

Comment: Schon Existenz und Beutung des Wortes [Kodierungstheorie](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kodierungstheorie) zeigen, dass *Kodierung* eine wesentlich breitere Bedeutung hat als Du voraussetzt - ich halte *kodieren* für die einzig halbwegs universelle Alternative Deiner Auswahl. Sollte man allerdings auf den höheren Schwierigkeitsgrad verglichen mit z. B. "HTML schreiben" abheben, kommt es auch nicht in Frage.

Comment: Die Umfrage auf nem Weihnachtsmarkt möcht ich sehen, in der die Mehrheit von "Existenz und Bedeutung" irgend eine Ahnung hat. Ich setze nicht voraus, ich schau aufs Maul. Die Allgemeinheit schreibt hier tatsächlich nicht, aber sie wird beschrieben. Ebenso wie Alternativen und Kontextinformationen. Zu jenen gehört die Feststellung, dass Zielgruppe des OP und germanSE nicht identisch oder nur kongruent sein müssen. It's a good thing.

Answer (score 3):

Hier ein mehr grafisch orienterter Vorschlag. Nehmen wir an, der Websiteinhaber heißt Peter:

[image: Peter schreibt Code]

Oder wo's technisch möglich ist ohne den Umweg über ein Bild auch so:

> `Peter schreibt <Code!>`

---

**Nachtrag**:

Zur Frage der "Länge" dieser Lösung (was in den Kommentaren unten verschiedentlich bekrittelt wird):

Der OP hat zwar formuliert, er suche einen "kürzeren" Ausdruck für *programmieren*. Das kann (!) man verstehen als "kürzer als das Wort *programmieren*". Doch im weiteren Text seiner Frage erläutert er, dass es ihm eigentlich um einen Ausdruck geht, mit dem er kurz und knapp darstellen kann, was er beruflich (o.ä.) macht, und offensichtlich gefällt ihm *programmieren* nicht.

Nun ist "*schreibt Code*" von der Zeichenzahl her nicht viel sparsamer als "*programmiert*"; aber die Anmutung des Ausdrucks ist dennoch: kurz, knapp, eindeutig, ohne Umschweife. Das liegt wohl daran, dass *schreibt Code* aus sehr einfachen, kurzen, eindeutigen Wörtern besteht. *Programmieren* als viersilbiges Fremdwort wirkt dagegen eher umständlich und schwerfällig.

Ich vermute darum, dass der OP "*schreibt Code*" eine gute Lösung findet. Was er übrigens in den Kommentaren selbst bestätigt hat.

Comment: Auch eine super Idee, danke

Comment: Und vor allem so viel kürzer als "programmiert"....

Comment: Nur bitte wirklich "schreibt" nehmen, und nicht "macht" ;)

Comment: @LangLangC   "Tut"?

Comment: @tofro  Höre ich da Spott heraus? Nimm dies, du Wicht! "Pro-gram-miert": drei Silben. "Schreibt-Code": zwei Silben. (Oder... vielleicht kann man darüber auch streiten... hm... aber nach dem beliebten Silbenklatschmodell sind's jedenfalls zwei.)

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Aber bei der Frage ging es ja um Geschriebenes und nicht um Gesprochenes, daher sollte man schon die Buchstaben bzw. Zeichen zählen und nicht die Silben. Insofern ist tofros Spott durchaus gerechtfertigt. BTW: Zumindest in den 90ern hätte LaTeX beim Zeilenumbruch aus "schreibt" völlig hemmungslos ein 2-silbiges schre- ibt gemacht, wie ich aus leidvoller Erfahrung berichten kann...

Comment: Beim Blick auf die Votes: Manchen Korinthenliebhabern hier kann man es ja nie recht machen, aber heute ist wohl schlechte Laune im Land der Richter und Henker?

Comment: @LangLangC  Ja, ich wundere mich auch über die vielen Downvotes, vor allem die, die ohne erklärenden Kommentar bleiben. Vielleicht ist es der Neid?