# Partizip II von "scrapen"

Tags: conjugation, loanword

Ich überarbeite einen Text über Data Scraping, in dem gehäuft Verbformen von "scrapen" (denglish zu "to scrape") verwendet werden. Wenn es nach mir ginge, würde ich die am liebsten ganz ersetzen, aber das wird wohl nichts. Stellt sich die Frage, wie man das vernünftig konjugiert ...

Was mir beim Versuch, ein Partizip zu bilden, auffällt: Bei "ich habe die Daten gescraped" wirkt m.E. ein "d" besser, bei "die gescrapeten Daten" eher ein "t" (und der vorliegende Text verwendet sogar ab und zu "gescrapt", was eher an "to scrap" = "verschrotten" erinnert!). Gibt es hierzu Empfehlungen?

Comment: Siehe auch: [Wie ist die richtige Schreibweise – "geliket"? "geliked"?](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/4435/2594)

Answer (score 6):

Fremdwörter können orthographisch oder morphologisch integriert werden. Sobald das deutsche Präfix *ge-* an das Verb herantritt, hat man sich für die morphologische Integration entschieden; dann muss es *gescrapt* heißen, erst recht, wenn noch eine deutsche Adjektivendung hinzukommt: *die gescrapten Daten*.

Das englische stumme *-e*, das der Anzeige des diphthongierten Stammvokals dient, verschwindet bei der Integration ins deutsche Flexionssystem.

> *nicht*: die gescrapeten Daten, er scrapet
> *sondern*: die gescrapten Daten, er scrapt

Sowohl die Gliederung *gescrape-t* mit *-e* als Teil des Stammes als auch *gescrap-et* mit *-e-* als Teil der Ednung sind systemwidrig: es gibt keine Stämme auf *-e* und das *-e-* der Endungen folgt aus allgemeinen Regeln (z.B. nach *d* oder *t* des Stammes): *er download-et* wie *er bad-et*, aber *er scrap-t* wie *er schab-t*.

Die Integration zeigt sich in der ersten Person bei Formen wie *ich lik-e* /laikə/, *scrap-e* /skreipə/: an den Stamm ohne stummes *-e* tritt die Personalendung *-e*.

Die Gefahr einer falschen Aussprache ist nicht so groß, wie es auf den ersten Blick scheinen mag. Auch im Englischen verschwindet stummes *-e* in Verbindung mit Suffixen, ohne dass sich die Aussprache ändert: *scraping, scraper, scrapable*. In diesen Kontexten wird die Opposition zu den undiphthongierten Lauten dadurch sichergestellt, dass nach diesen der Konsonant verdoppelt wird: *scrapping, scrapper, scrappable*. Das passt sehr gut ins deutsche System: *scrappen, er scrappt, gescrappt*.

Die morphologische Integration entspricht den Empfehlungen des Duden: [das Verb "liken"](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/Das-Verb-liken), [Konjugation zu *faken*](https://www.duden.de/konjugation/faken). Siehe auch die Duden-Grammatik, 10. Auflage, Randnummer 1665.

Comment: Nachfrage: weil das 'e' auch im Englischen nicht zum Wortstamm gehört, genau deshalb heißt es  im Deutschen nicht 'gescrapet'? Man verwendet also den gleichen Wortstamm mit deutscher Konjugation?

Comment: So isset: Ganz oder gar nicht. Nutzt man ein deutsches Partizippräfix wie "ge-", kann man kein englisches Partizippostfix wie "-ed" mehr dranhängen.

Comment: Die Schreibung "gescrapt" und die englische Aussprache des Stamms mit "[skreip]" schließen sich aus,  und ich finde die Argumentation, dass der Wortstamm "scrap-" sein muss, nur weil der Infinitiv "scrapen" heißt, auch nicht überzeugend. Als Infinitiv wäre eigentlich "scrape-en" sinnvoll, was man bei dieser Art Verben *für den infinitiv sinnvoll* zu scrapen verkürzt hat. Daraus abzuleiten, man solle auch "du scrapst", "er scrapt", "gescrapt" etc. schreiben, ist m.E. ein grammatiktheoretischer Schwanz, der mit dem Hund wedelt.

Comment: Die Aussprache im Englischen ändert sich allerdings, sobald kein Vokal folgt. (Es heißt _I scraped_ und nicht _I scrapd_.) Daher ist schon zu konstatieren, dass _gescrapt_ in Disanalogie zur englischen Morphologie steht. Das ist es, woran sich die Intuition derer reibt, die _gescraped_ schreiben wollen. Der Dissens besteht m.M nach darin, ob man diese im Deutschen "systemwidrige" Konstruktion ins Deutsche überträgt: Gibt man der Analogie zum Englischen, oder der Systemtreue im Deutschen den Vorzug?

Comment: @JonathanScholbach Wie soll sich denn die Aussprache  "automatisch" ändern? Das entscheidet doch der Sprecher? Man sollte präziser formulieren und sagen: *gelikt, gefakt* könnten falsch ausgesprochen werden, wenn das *-e* als Signal fehlt. Aber das trifft für *geliket, gefaket* genauso zu (falsche dreisilbige Aussprache möglich). Wenn man für die nichtdiphthongierten Vokale Doppelkonsonanten als Signal hat, ist zumindest eine Opposition sichergestellt (*Download gecappt, Batman gecapt*).

Comment: Lass uns das heir weiter besprechen: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145209/partizip-ii-von-scrapen

Comment: Ich sehe schon: Trotz teils verschiedener Positionen ist wohl die überwigende und gut begründbare Lösung, dass es erstens "gescrapt" heißt. Wegen teils verschiedener Positionen wäre es wohl die beste Lösung, wenn das Wort gescrappt würden :)

Comment: Toller Kommentar. Was wäre nun mit "Orthographischer Integration" gemeint? Dass man es so umschreibt, wie man es für richtig geschrieben hält, ohne dabei auf morpho(-syntaktische?/logische) Regeln zu achten?

Comment: @OranMatheus Orthographische Integration meint, dass man an die deutsche Laut-Buchstaben-Zuordnung anpasst: *strike > Streik, Sauce > Soße*.

Comment: Danke, was wäre die Zuordnung für "scrapen"?

Comment: Bei "streiken" hat man also "Strike" sowohl orthographisch als auch morphologisch ins Deutsche integriert, verstehe ich das richtig? Es schließt sich nicht aus?

Comment: @OranMatheus *Streiken* ist in jeder Hinsicht integriert und nicht mehr von einem einheimischen Wort unterscheidbar. – So was wie *cakes > Keks* würde man heute mit *scrape* nicht mehr machen. Könnte mir vorstellen, dass die Aussprache bei häufigem Gebrauch von fremdem /ei/ zu nativem /e/ wechseln könnte. Aber nur, wenn es kein Fachbegriff bleibt. Das wäre dann phonologische Integration.

Comment: Vielen Dank. Wenn ein Wort "in jeder Hinsicht integriert" ist, kann man also sagen, dass es sowohl morphologisch als auch orthographisch (und somit auch phonologisch) integriert ist?

Comment: @OranMatheus Ja. Wobei orthographische und phonologische Integration nicht das Gleiche ist: *Training* wird geschrieben wie im Englischen (bis auf Großschreibung), kann aber mit einem Monophthong gesprochen werden; *Tipp* hat ein zweites P bekommen, was die Aussprache aber nicht ändert.

Comment: @DavidVogt Damit wäre das geklärt. Danke, das war sehr hilfreich und hat Klarheit geschaffen!

Answer (score 2):

Für manche aus dem Englischen abgeleitete Wörter, die nicht auf -e enden, hat sich durchgesetzt, dass im Deutschen in den konjugierten Formen ein e eingefügt wird.

> *downloaden*: ich downloade, du downloadest, er/sie/es downloadet, wir downloaden, ihr downloadet, sie downloaden, downloadend, gedownloadet.

(also analog zu *warten*: ich warte, er wartet, wartend, gewartet)

Bei anderen hingegen nicht:

> powern: ich powere, du powerst, er powert, wir powern, ihr powert, sie powern, powernd, gepowert

Bei englischen Verben, die auf -e eden, ändert das -e die Aussprache der Silbe davor. Wenn man dieses -e weglässt, ändert sich die gelesene Aussprache. Wenn die englische Aussprache [skrɛip] bei der Eindeutschung "scrapen" als [skrɛipen] erhalten bleiben soll, kommt man um das (dann stumme) -e nicht herum:

> scrapen: ich scrape [skrɛipə], du scrapest [skrɛipst], gescrapet [geskrɛipt]

Weglassen des -e (also *gescrapt*) würde die englische Silbe zerstören und damit intransparent machen, dass eine englische Aussprache von [skrɛip] gemeint ist. Die Verwechslung mit *"to scrap"* wäre unausweichlich, wenn man nicht Vorwissen über das eingedeutschte Verb mitbringt.

Weiteres Beispiel:

> liken: ich like, du likest, geliket

Wenn man es deskriptiv betrachtet, sieht es allerdings ganz anders aus:

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=geliked%2C+geliket%2C+gelikt&year_start=2000&year_end=2019&corpus=de-2019&smoothing=3

Bei weitem am populärsten ist dort "geliked", gefolgt von "gelikt" (reines Glück, dass es kein englisches verb *to lik* gibt) und abgeschlagen "geliket". Für "scrape" gibt es dort leider zu wenig Daten.

Comment: Dies erscheint mir auch logischer als dass das e bei scrape verschwindet. Danke dir für die Übersicht... auch wenn ich die meisten dieser englischen Verben nur im Gesprochenen verwende, nicht zuletzt, weil es geschrieben mit immer etwas arg bemüht aussieht, egal wie man es schreibt

Comment: *Wenn man dieses -e weglässt, ändert sich die gelesene Aussprache.* Warum? Durch welche Magie? Im Englischen jedenfalls nicht: *scraping, scraper, scrapable* werden trotz fehlendem *e* nie /ae/ gelesen. Die Verwechslung mit *scrap* wird durch Konsonantendopplung ausgeschlossen: *scrapping, scrapper, scrappable*. Der Duden hat mit dem fehlenden *e* kein Problem: [gelikt](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/Das-Verb-liken), [gefakt](https://www.duden.de/konjugation/faken).

Comment: @DavidVogt: aber im Englschen auch "he likes", "she fakes", "liked", "faked". Und da soll man sich bei der Bildung der dritten Person und des Partizips im Deutschen eher an "liking" und der amerikanischen Verkürzung "likable" (in BE: "likeable") orientieren? Das ergibt für mich nur wenig Sinn.

Comment: 1. *Gelike-t, gelik-et* sind systemwidrig (dt. keine Stämme auf *-e*, kein *-et* nach *k*). 2. Engl. hat *lik* /laik/, *scrap* /skreip/ vor *-ed, -ing, -er, -y, -able*, etc. (dass es *-able* auch nach *-e* gibt ist egal; es geht nur darum, dass es Diphthongierung ohne *-e* geben kann, was immer geleugnet wird, wenn jemand "*gelikt* kann nicht /ai/ haben" o.ä. vertritt). 3. Deutsches *gescrap-t, gelik-t* entspricht nicht den englischen Konventionen, muss das aber auch nicht. Fehllesungen sind durch fehlende Konsonantenkopplung (*gescrappt, gelickt*) ausgeschlossen (daher kein Glück in Spiel).

Answer (score 2):

Es gibt ja bereits eine ganze Reihe englischer Wörter, die es als Fremdwörter in den deutschen Wortschatz und damit auch in die Flexionstabellen mancher Wörterbücher geschafft haben. Das Verb *»scrapen«* habe ich zwar noch nicht gefunden, aber man wird es im Deutschen wohl gleich beugen müssen wie andere ähnlich klingende Verben, die schon als Fremdwörter in deutschen Wörterbüchern stehen, und für die es auch Flexionstabellen gibt. Derzeit scheint es nur ein Wort zu geben, das als Vorlage für *»scrapen«* geeignet ist, und das ist:

- [tapen](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/tapen)
  Einen stützenden Verband aus einem klebenden Band (Tape) herstellen.
  Auf Wiktionary gibt es auch eine vollständige [Flexionstabelle](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Flexion:tapen) zu diesem Verb. Es gibt auch einen Eintag über [tapen im DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/tapen), allerdings stehen dort falsche Verwendungsbeispiele und im DWDS gibt es keine vollständigen Flexionstabellen. (Ein weiterer Grund, warum ich Wiktionary gegenüber allen anderen Wörterbüchern vorziehe.) Mit Hilfe der Flexionstabelle aus Wiktionary lassen sich leicht diese Beispielsätze bilden:

  > Ich tape Jürgens Knie.
  > Martin tapt Jürgens Knie.
  > Mach schon, tape endlich Jürgens Knie!
  > Ich habe Jürgens Knie getapt.
  > Jürgen kann nun das getapte Knie wieder belasten.

Wie gesagt gibt es für *»scrapen«* noch keine Wörterbucheinträge, aber ich würde dieses Wort einfach ganz gleich beugen wie *»tapen«:*

- scrapen

  > Ich scrape eine Website.
  > Jürgen scrapt eine Website.
  > Mach schon, scrape endlich diese Website!
  > Ich habe die Website gescrapt.
  > Wir haben die gescrapte Website in der Datenbank gespeichert.

**Wichtig! (Aussprache)**
Die Verben *»tapen«* und *»scrapen«* sind keine Lehnwörter, sondern Fremdwörter. Lehnwörter würde man so aussprechen als wären sie deutsche Wörter.<sup>1</sup> Bei Fremdwörtern verwendet man aber die Aussprache der Originalsprache, daher werden *»tapen«* und *»scrapen«* auch in einem deutschen Kontext ausgesprochen wie im Englischen, also [ˈtɛɪ̯pn̩] (ähnlich wie *teipn*) und [ˈskɹeɪpn̩] (ähnlich wie *skreipn*).

Die Vorsilbe *ge-*, die bei der Bildung des Partizips vorne an das Verb angefügt wird, wird aber weiterhin deutsch ausgesprochen, so dass bei den Partizipien *getapt* und *gescrapt* mitten im Wort die Ausspracheregeln von deutsch auf englisch wechseln. Heraus kommt dann:

- getapt = [ɡəˈtɛɪ̯pt] (ähnlich wie *geteipt*)
- gescrapt = [ɡəˈskɹeɪpt] (ähnlich wie *geskreipt*).

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Ein typisches Beispiel für ein Lehnwort ist das aus dem Englischen stammende Wort [Jute](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Jute), das in einem deutschen Kontext deutsch (also als [ˈjuːtə]) ausgesprochen wird, während das Wort [jute](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/jute) in der Originalsprache English als [d͡ʒuːt] (ähnlich wie *dschuut*) ausgesprochen wird.</sub>

Comment: warum eliminiert man aber das für die Aussprache wichtige 'e'? Warum schreibt man nicht "getapet" bzw. "gescrapet"? Die meisten auf DWDS genannten Beispiele sind eher für das Verb tap(p)en.

Comment: @planetmaker: Auf die schlechte Qualität des Eintrags bei DWDS habe ich ohnehin ausdrücklich hingewiesen. Warum empfindest du das *e* als wichtig? Wenn man es stehen ließe, enstünden ja die Wörter *"getapet"* und *"gescrapet"* die mich zu den Aussprachen [ɡəˈtɛɪ̯pət] und [ɡəˈskɹeɪpət] verleiten würden. Es ist auch wichtig zu verstehen, dass nicht die Aussprache der Schrift folgen soll, sondern das die Aufgabe der Schrift darin besteht, das gesprochene Wort zu konservieren und transportabel zu machen. Die primäre ...

Comment: ... Frage ist also nicht »Wie soll man ein Wort aussprechen, das *"getapt"* oder *getapet* geschrieben wird?« Wichiger ist diese Frage: »Wie soll man ein Wort schreiben, dessen Aussprache [ɡəˈskɹeɪpt] ist?« Und wenn ich versuchen sollte, diese Frage zu beantworten, käme ich nie auf die Idee, zwischen *p* und *t* einen Vokal zu schreiben, denn es wird an dieser Stelle kein Vokal gesprochen.

Comment: Und beim Weglassen des 'e' besteht die Verwechslung mit der durchaus auch vorhandenen Eindeutschung von (to) tap (=berühren, klopfen) - getapt oder (to) scrap (=verschrotten) - gescrapt. Insofern erscheint mir das Erhalten des bedeutungsgebenden Teil des Verbs sinnvoller als es ggf. sinnentstellend an der Endung zu beschneiden. Das 'e' ist im Englischen ja auch stumm und definiert genau den Ausspracheunterschied zwischen scrap und scrape bzw. tap und tape