# Construction of past participle of borrowed verbs

Tags: english-to-german, past-participle

No surprise a past participle of a verb imported from English goes with the *ge-* form, because it's the commonest.

But I've heard Germans say

> *gedownloadet*

and, on the other hand,

> *upgeloadet*

Can you tell me the linguistic reason behind this difference in the placement?

Comment: Related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2358

Comment: I've heard *Der Flug war gecanceled* or something like that.

Comment: @c.p.: Right, but there is no prefix candidate in _canceln_.

Comment: I would say "geuploadet", others say "downgeloadet"... there are no rules yet

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not immediately clear whether *uploaden* and *downloaden* in German should be treated as monolithic words or as having separable prefixes. Therefore, *geuploadet*, *upgeloadet*, *gedownloadet* and *downgeloadet* can all be found in the wild, as can spelling variants with *-ed*. If you have only encountered one version per verb, that is by accident.

The general tendency nowadays for both is toward them being considered partially separable verbs: Separable for purposes of the past participle, inseparable otherwise (*ich downloade*, not *ich loade down*). Many people avoid them altogether.

Comment: Interestingly, in a Google fight, *upgeloadet* and *geuploadet* are equally popular, while *gedownloadet* is four times as popular as *downgeloadet.* This might be explained by the collision of two vowels in *geuploadet,* which makes the word more difficult to read and somewhat clumsy in pronunciation.

Comment: Also, I cannot state often enough that the variants ending on *-ed* are [wrong on many levels](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/4435/wie-ist-die-richtige-schreibweise-geliket-geliked/4998#4998).