# Imperative/perfect tense of inserperable verbs (maybe only loan words?)

Tags: separable-verb, loanword

A discussion with Wrzlprmft [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/81874/when-exactly-are-you-promoviert-in-germany/81884?noredirect=1#comment203349_81884), referred me to the question [“Gedownloadet” oder “downgeloadet”](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2358/gedownloadet-oder-downgeloadet). It asked whether the perfect tense of the loanword *downloaden* is *downgeloadet* or *gedownloadet.*

As I said in my comment to the original question,

> I decide first if the verb is separable. Try the imperative, "Hey, Du, date das up" - doesn't work, so it must be "hey, Du, update das", which makes the part tense also inseparable – geupdatet

My question, in several parts, is:

- Is there a German grammar rule, with respect to the perfect tense of inseparable verbs? If so, what is it?
- Does it apply to loan words?
- Can I determine a separable verb the way I did above, by looking at the imperative? Or is there a better way/rule? If so, what is it?

Comment: Your first and third questions are answered in every grammar book.

Comment: Of course, I only asked "is there a rule" - I forgot to ask "what is the rule?" :-)

Comment: There is a rule and you can find it in every grammar book. Or with a simple google search request.

Comment: GGood old BBC :-)  http://www.bbc.co.uk/schools/gcsebitesize/german/grammar/verbsseparablerev2.shtml  What about quesiton #2 ?

Comment: Do you know any separable loan word?

Comment: I try never to use loan words.  I will think about it. Feel free to post an answer ...

Comment: @Eller You have inspired http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/33858/are-there-any-seperable-german-loan-words-from-english   ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wether a verb is seperable or not is only relevant for verbs with prefixes. Sagen:
durch-sagen, an-sagen, ver-sagen, zu-sagen, unter-sagen, ent-sagen etc.
Unseparable verbs (f.e. entsagen) don't have "ge" anywhere in the past pariciple (ich habe dem Alkohol **entsagt**).

There are no rules for loan words. "to upload" feels very separable, because of the quite literal meaning of "up" as prefix. That's why a German would rather use the past participle "upgeloadet". But this 'feeling' has impact only on the past participle. loan words generally aren't seperated. The imperative would be: "uploade/update das bitte!" But far more common is the use of the noun: "Mach bitte ein Update!"

There are German verbs for upload/download: **hochladen** and (he)**runterladen**, both separable. Just use them ;)