# Lieder auf ein Gerät herunterladen

Tags: grammar, verb-usage

> Ich habe 66 Lieder von den Prinzen auf mein Smartphone/Gerät heruntergeladen.

Kann man hier auch jeweils `uploaden` und `downloaden` verwenden?

Comment: related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1041/how-to-translate-the-word-download-to-german

Comment: Ich habe 66 Songs von den Prinzen auf mein Smartphone gedownloadet. Das einzige originär deutsche Wort mit mehr als vier Buchstaben ist ein Eigenname ;)

Comment: Generell: Was weiter entfernt ist, ist "oben". Wo man sich gedanklich befindet, ist "unten". Wenn ich aus dem Internet auf das Smartphone transferiere, nehme ich "herunterladen", aber wenn ich von meinem PC auf dein Smartphone transferiere, nehme ich "hochladen".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Downloading or transferring data is most of the times used as this:

> Ich habe dir die Dateien auf the USB-Stick geladen/kopiert.

I have transferred the data to the USB stick.

Still, as mentioned in the comment you can use `down-` or `uploaden` in this case as well.

Comment: `Machen` sounds very colloquial, you'd rather say _Ich habe dir die Dateien auf den USB-Stick kopiert_.

Comment: The community agreed on not correcting minor mistakes in questions in the answer, but instead suggest an or edit.

Comment: I would rather like to explain them. Thats why.

Comment: Anyway Lars is right, "machen" is wrong here. For me, this is the same usage as in "ich habe jemanden tot gemacht" - not the right verb at all!

Comment: @christian.s: There's more than the verb wrong about that sentence...

Comment: Slightly off topic but still:  
In this case you'd write "von Den Prinzen", as "Die Prinzen" is a name and the 'Die' is Part of it.